# How to replace the authorization policy of a WebApplicationFactory in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authorization

I'm writing *Integration Tests* and I've constructed an xUnit test fixture that's meant to be instantiated only once. Within this fixture, I've set up a WebApplicationFactory as follows, with a service that handles authentication and authorization:

```
public IntegrationTestFixture()
{
    var webApplicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(webHostBuilder =>
    {
        webHostBuilder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("IntegrationTests")
                    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, AuthHandler>("IntegrationTests", options => { });

            services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
            {
                authorizationOptions.AddPolicy("Default policy", authorizationPolicy =>
                    authorizationPolicy.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                          .AddAuthenticationSchemes("IntegrationTests")
                          .RequireClaim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I need to be able to replace the existing authorization policy of the above WebApplicationFactory, from within the following method, which is located inside the same class/fixture:

```
public void ReplaceAuthorizationPolicy(string newPolicy)
{
    AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy;

    authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("IntegrationTests")
            .RequireClaim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType)
            .Build();

    authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(newPolicy, authorizationPolicy);
}
```

In the above method, I can't figure out how to retrieve the WebApplicationFactory's AuthorizationOptions service and either (1) perform ".AddPolicy(newPolicy, authorizationPolicy)" on that service, or (2) replace it altogether with the AuthorizationOptions service that I've initiated within the method. I'm fine with either solution as long as it works, but how do I achieve one of these?

Comment: WebApplicationFactory.WithWebHostBuilder creates a new WebApplicationFactory instance that allows this type of configuration.  You are already calling this when initializing the fixture.  You may be able to utilize this method again to do what you want.  If may be useful to see the full fixture code to have a better idea of what you're trying to do and how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC Policy Override in Integration Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379327/mvc-policy-override-in-integration-tests)